# Apply Page-break on mat-table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

i have component print-template which contains  and
i pass Mat-table inside  from Datatoprint component.

i want to apply page-break when i print a table with lots of rows,it should go to next page after certain rows.
i tried applying print to table directly it works fine. it automatically goes to next page after certain row. but in my case it is not working.

is that because table is inside another component or it's because of ?
Please help Thank you

**PrintTemplate.html**

```
<div>Header</div>
<div>
    Mattable
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div>Footer</div>
```

**DataToPrint.html**

```
<app-print-template>
<table mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th></th>
        <td></td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
</app-print-template>
```

What i tried?
i have applied this css but did not work.

```
@media print{
  table {
    //display:block;
    page-break-inside: auto;
  }
  tr.element-row:nth-child(20n) {
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the following to my `styles.scss` (not inside `@page` or `@media print`)

```css
tr {
  page-break-after: auto;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
     
table {
  page-break-inside: auto;
}
```